# get response json request with volley

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that communicate with a RESTful web service I wrote. Using Volley for GET methods is awesome and easy, but I can't put my finger on the POST methods.

how i can take field from a response of my post request 
this is my response

```
enter code here

"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkFXOFR"
IDgGvCSwgGU2sGL1-zdEyP9HqIpPFGnJwoRv-zDE_7Kp7s8NG4jrrquAJNmbQapMn- 
jgNbb0FXqiDOD9keaAjwJ0GyEZqxM9iLTI2GZykaIhm- 
VPpIMnC25b1Ieoqnypw2T9oyTmzFNwGYDefN_x80Go3unlzA_- 
_sAVNTGSTYGgxtIdjmsmbH8k6HKHA",

"token_type": "bearer",

"expires_in": "3600",

"resource": "urn:microsoft:userinfo",
```

I want to have only  "access token" content

this is my code

```
enter code here
private void userLogin() {
    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                        openProfile();

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        token=response;





                    }
                }


            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }

            ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

please help me ?!

Answer (score 1):

Create `JSONObject` from `String` and get values form the `JSONObject` with corresponding keys. Use this code inside `onResponse` method to get token from the response string:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
String token = obj.getString("access_token");
String tokenType = obj.getString("token_type");
String expiresIn = obj.getString("expires_in");
String resource = obj.getString("resource");
```

If you have RESTful web service then [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is a good choice. It's a type-safe HTTP client. It will automatically convert your response to Java 
object. You don't need to convert it manually.